# Executing update query in django using JSON

Tags: python, sql, json, django

The tasks i implemented are,

1. store  a `json` file as the string in the database.
2. Each `json` file represents a query that can execute against a database `table` . Some examples are

example 1

```
{ "name:"testrule1","query":"select * from students"}
```

To execute the query and get the result the user have to call the url

http://127.0.0.1/myview?testrule1

example2

```
{ "name:"updaterule1","query":"UPDATE students SET name=%s, id=%s" where age=10}
```

To update the table with name = sample and id=206 user have to call the url.

http://127.0.0.1/myview?updaterule1&sample&206

my objective is to store multiple json string like this in the database and
execute the corresponding query on the url call.

But update query is not working properly. what can i do to make it working?
The queries and stored on database in django as json data.
These are my files.

views.py

```
def view1(request,title):
    p=query.objects.get(name=title)
    cursor=connection.cursor()
    cursor.execute(p.data["query"])
    return HttpResponse(cursor.fetchall())

def view2(request,title,nam,roll):
    cursor=connection.cursor()
    q=query.objects.get(name=title)
    p=Post.objects.raw(q.data["query"],[nam],[roll])
    cursor.execute(q.data["query"]) 
    transaction.commit()
    h=Post.objects.raw('select * from posts_post')
    return HttpResponse(h)
```

urls.py

```
from django.conf.urls import url
from django.contrib import admin 

urlpatterns = [
    url(r'^admin/', admin.site.urls),
    url(r'^posts/$', 'posts.views.posts_home'),
    url(r'^create/$', 'posts.views.create'),   
    url(r'^results/$', 'posts.views.results'),
    url(r'^myview/(?P<title>[\w]+)/$', 'posts.views.view1'),
    url(r'^myview/(?P<title>[\w]+)&(?P<nam>[\w]+)&(?P<roll>      \d+)/$','posts.views.view2'),
]
```

Comment: You really shouldn't be accepting and executing SQL queries from a client in this way... you should also be using the Django ORM instead of raw SQL.

Comment: queries are acutually fetched from django sqllite database

Comment: As @solarissmoke pointed out, you really, really don't want to do this (unless of course you are creating a site like sqlfiddle). The second point is that you don't really seem to need JSON. You can just save the query as a string. (I note that you are only using the query field and discarding the other field)

Comment: how can i perform update query?